# Merge a Branch in VSS: You cannot perform a merge on a binary file, or a file that stores latest version

Tags: merge, visual-sourcesafe

Maybe I'm dumb, or just stupid.

But I'm stuck on-site in an enterprise where VSS is the 'option'.

So i had to branch my code, which was reasonbly easy.

However when it came time to merge back into the main line in VSS, things got screwy.

First, i couldn't merge by project, or even by folder but only file-by-file.

Then I tried the recommended command line: ss merge $/root/project/project/folder/*.*

That produced the following error:

"You cannot perform a merge on a binary file, or a file that stores latest versio
n only."

Searching on this error message produces a lot of info about cvs, subversion and git.

That's because the words in that sentence are used in the text of those other posts.

Does anyone think that this error is about the two 'modes' that VSS will work in?

I mean, does Lock-Modify-Unlock and Copy-Modify-Merge make a difference here?

In any case, when I try to merge i might as well use a diff utility and then check in the changes from one 'branch' to the other because merge and branch do not produce the necessary modifications in the files to keep the versions straight.

Thanks,

Stato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you are trying to perform Merge either on a binary file or a file that set to store only the latest version.

This should have nothing to do with the mode.